# Principal component analysis using R. Automatic and manual results do not match

Tags: r, statistics, pca

Two different methods of the principal component analysis were conducted to analyze the following data ([ch082.dat](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xykl6ln-bUnXIs-jIA3n5S3XgHjQbkWB/view?usp=sharing))  using the Box1's R-code, below.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xykl6ln-bUnXIs-jIA3n5S3XgHjQbkWB/view?usp=sharing

The first method uses the rotation matrix (See 'ans_mat' under the '#rotated data' of the Box1's code) and,
the second method uses the 'pcomp' function (See 'rpca' under the '#rotated data' of the Box1's code).

However, there is a subtle discrepancy in the answer between the method using the rotation matrix and the method using the 'pcomp' function.
make it match

**My Question**

> What should I do so that the result of the rotation matrix -based method matches the result of the'pcomp' function?

As far as I've tried with various data, including other data, the actual discrepancies seem to be limited to scale shifts and mirroring transformations.

- The results of the rotation matrix -based method is shown in left panel.
- The results of the pcomp function -based method is shown in right panel.

Mirror inversion can be seen in "ch082.dat" data.(See Fig.1);
It seems that, in some j, the sign of the "jth eigenvector of the correlation matrix" and the sign of the "jth column of the output value of the prcomp function" may be reversed. If there is a degree of overlap in the eigenvalues, it is possible that the difference may be more complex than mirror inversion.
[image]
Fig.1

There is a scale shift for the Box2's data (See See Fig.2), despite the centralization and normalization to the data.
[image]
Fig.2

**Box.1**

```
#dataload
##Use the 'setwd' function to specify the directory containing 'ch082.dat'.
##For example, if you put this file directly under the C drive of your Windows PC, you can run the following command.

setwd("C:/") #Depending on where you put the file, you may need to change the path.
getwd()
w1<-read.table("ch082.dat",header = TRUE,row.names = 1,fileEncoding = "UTF-8")
w1

#Function for standardizing data
#Thanks to https://qiita.com/ohisama2/items/5922fac0c8a6c21fcbf8
standalize <- function(data)
{ for(i in length(data[1,]))
{
  x <- as.matrix(data[,i])
  y <- (x-mean(x)/sd(x))
  data[,i] <- y
}
  return(data)}


#Method using rotation matrix
z_=standalize(w1)
B_mat=cor(z_) #Compute correlation matrix
eigen_m <- eigen(B_mat)
sample_mat <- as.matrix(z_)
ans_mat=sample_mat

for(j in 1:length(sample_mat[1,])){
ans_mat[,j]=sample_mat%*%eigen_m$vectors[,j]
}

#Method using "rpca" function
rpca <- prcomp(w1,center=TRUE, scale=TRUE)

#eigen vectors
eigen_m$vectors
rpca

#rotated data
ans_mat
rpca$x

#Graph　Plots
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(
  ans_mat[,1], 
  ans_mat[,2], 
  main="Rotation using eigenvectors"
)
plot(rpca$x[,1], rpca$x[,2], 
     main="Principal component score")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))

#summary
summary(rpca)$importance
```

Box2.

```
sample_data <- data.frame(
  X = c(2,4, 6, 5,7, 8,10),
  Y = c(6,8,10,11,9,12,14)
)

X = c(2,4, 6, 5,7, 8,10)
Y = c(6,8,10,11,9,12,14)
plot(Y ~ X)

w1=sample_data
```

**Reference**
https://logics-of-blue.com/principal-components-analysis/
(Written in Japanease)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two sets of results agree. First we can simplify your code a bit. You don't need your function or the for loop:

```
z_ <- scale(w1)
B_mat <- cor(z_)
eigen_m <- eigen(B_mat)
ans_mat <- z_ %*% eigen_m$vectors
```

Now the `prcomp` version

```
z_pca <- prcomp(z_)
z_pca$sdev^2    # Equals eigen_m$values
z_pca$rotation  # Equals eigen_m$vectors
z_pca$x         # Equals ans_mat
```

Your original code mislabeled `ans_mat` columns. They are actually the principal component scores. You can fix that with

```
colnames(ans_mat) <- colnames(z_pca$x)
```

The pc loadings (and therefore the scores) are not uniquely defined with respect to reflection. In other words multiplying all of the loadings or scores in one component by -1 flips them but does not change their relationships to one another. Multiply `z_pca$x[, 1]` by -1 and the plots will match:

```
z_pca$x[, 1] <- z_pca$x[, 1] * -1
dev.new(width=10, height=6)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(ans_mat[,1], ans_mat[,2], main="Rotation using eigenvectors")
plot(z_pca$x[,1], z_pca$x[,2], main="Principal component score")
```

[image: PCA plots]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I modified the code according to your instructions, but, for [my data](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1SH3D5NY-SzxTY22IA-Mnx6R73xbxUt3-), still eigen_m$vectors[,1]=- z_pca$rotation[,1] .

Comment: For the Box2's data, the final result seems to be in agreement. The plot corresponding to FIG. 2 of the interrogative text, the scales of the two methods matched.

Comment: I should have noticed that. The pc loadings (and therefore the scores) are not uniquely defined with respect to reflection. In other words multiplying all of the loadings or scores in one component by -1 flips them but does not change their relationship to one another. Multiply ans_mat[, 1] or rpca$x[, 1] by -1, but not both, and the plots will match. Currently they are mirror images of one another.

Comment: >"pc loadings (and therefore the scores) are not uniquely defined with respect to reflection."⇒Thank you very much. It's all clear now. So, If we multiply the eigenvector by a non-zero scalar, it is still an eigenvector corresponding to the same eigenvalue.
If the eigenspaces are two or more dimensional, it is still an eigenvector corresponding to the same eigenvalue even if we do a transformation that preserves the eigenspaces, as long as the orthogonality is maintained..
Therefore, principal component analysis has an arbitrary nature in this sense, am I right?　Thank you.

Comment: Yes although multiplying by any value other than 1, -1 will change the relationship of the eigenvector/scores to the eigenvalue.

Comment: Thank you. So, only orthogonal transformations that preserve the eigenspaces of all eigenvalues are allowed, am I right?

Comment: Thank you very much!!